# Start CSS3 animation with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to start this specific CSS animation with jquery when you click the button. no idea how. Any ideas?

THanks

```
    <button>Click here to start the animation!!</button>
    <div id="ball"></div>

#ball {
    background:tomato;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border-radius:200px;
    position:absolute;
    animation:bounce 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:bounce 3s infinite;
    top:40px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    50% {
        top: calc(100% - 50px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounce {
    50% {
        top: calc(100% - 50px);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try to add the animation to a class and then give that element that class via jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple method would be to have the CSS animation properties on a seperate class and then toggle the class when the button is clicked.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpT4y/)

```
#ball.animate {
    animation:bounce 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:bounce 3s infinite;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('#ball').toggleClass('animate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use pure CSS3? There's no need to bring jQUery into the mix. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rxK3/1/) illustrating how to do it using nothing more than the `:checked` pseudo selector.